# Robots.txt on one line

Tags: seo, google, robots.txt

Can I combine robots.txt rules on one line, separated by whitespace?

Will this work?

```
User-agent: *  Disallow: /
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Maybe there's a different way to achieve the same thing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  See the [Google Robots.txt specifications](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt), specifically the File Formats section.

> The expected file format is plain text encoded in UTF-8. The file consists of records (lines) separated by CR, CR/LF or LF.
>
> Only valid records will be considered; all other content will be ignored. For example, if the resulting document is a HTML page, only valid text lines will be taken into account, the rest will be discarded without warning or error.

So line breaks between lines are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The file **MUST** consist of one or more records separated by one or more blank lines.

**Robots.txt must use this format:**

```
<field>:<optionalspace><value><optionalspace>
<field>:<optionalspace><value><optionalspace>
```

*Which looks like*:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

*Or without optional spaces and more line breaks:*

```
User-agent:*

Disallow:/
```

**Useful Links**

- [A Standard for Robot Exclusion](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html)
- [Robots Internet Draft](http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt)
- [Robots.txt Specifications](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt)

Comment: Where did you find that empty lines are allowed inside of a record? [AFAIR](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) they are only allowed to separate records.

Comment: On the standard for Robot Exclusion page, it details about the use of blank lines and optional spaces. It's important to note their is no REAL 'official robot standards' or guidelines but this is the very first original proposal and considered the standard.

Comment: Yeah, that is the spec I linked to. It says: "The file consists of one or more records separated by one or more blank lines. Each record contains lines of the form […]" — and there blank lines are not listed as allowed line *inside* of a record.

Comment: record = field, so field can be separated by a line.

Comment: No, a record is a whole block: "The record starts with one or more User-agent lines, followed by one or more Disallow lines […]". A line starts with a *field*, a *record* consists of lines.

Comment: Oops thats what I meant..... The way I read the rules is that you can have a complete field/record line (field+value) then a line then same again...